# using async to serialize operations with multiple layers of callbacks in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I'm fairly new to node and am having some trouble unravelling some callback hell.  I need to perform a series of involved operations -- each of which has a lot of code in modules with lots of callbacks.  But these operations need to be performed in series.  I've broken the real mess down to this toy program:

```
const 
    a = require('async');

var myasyncproc = function( cb ) {
    setTimeout( console.log( '..boo') , 10000 );
    var str = require('fs').createReadStream('atest.js');
    str.on('data', function( data ) {
        console.log( data );
    })
    str.on('end', function() { 
        cb();
    });
};

[1,2,3].forEach( function( i ) {    
    a.series( [
       function( callback ) {
         console.log( 'starting ' );
         myasyncproc( callback );
        },
        function( callback ) {
            console.log('too' );
            callback( null, 'too');
        },

        function( callback ) {
            console.log( 'tree' );
            callback( null, 'done');
        } 
        ], function (err, result ) {
            console.log( result);
        }
    );
});
```

Also note that I need to perform this series multiple times.  Here I've just used the vector [1,2,3], but in my real application, these have values I need to use.  If you run this, you'll see that the myasyncproc is called three times (started) before "too" and "tree" are run.

That's good, but how do I use async or some other technique to prevent a **second** call to myasyncproc until 'tree' is done?  Seems like async should do this, but I can't quite suss it out...

Thanks!

Comment: Use Promises - now it's kind of becoming standard for ecmascript control flow. Bluebird is the fastest realization - https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird

Comment: Since you're already using the `async` lib, check out `async.forEachSeries`.

Answer (score 0):

I did a small refactor to get you started:

```
var  async = require('async');

var myasyncproc = function( cb ) {
    console.log( '..boo')
    var str = require('fs').createReadStream('atest.js');
    str.on('data', function( data ) {
        console.log( data );
    })
    str.on('end', function() {
        cb(null, 'end'); // if you do cb(), you will return undefined as result
    });
};

var fns = [
       function( callback ) {
         console.log( 'starting ' );
         myasyncproc( callback );
        },
        function( callback ) {
            console.log('too' );
            callback( null, 'too');
        },

        function( callback ) {
            console.log( 'tree' );
            callback( null, 'done');
        }
        ];

var myItemArray = [1,2,3]; // just change this by your array of Item

async.eachSeries(myItemArray, function(item, callback){

    async.series( fns , function (err, result ) {
            console.log( result );
            callback(console.log("for item: "+item)) // callback needed to iterate
    });
}, function(err){

});
```

Here is the result i get with "yooo" in the atest.js file:

```
starting 
..boo
<Buffer 20 79 6f 6f 6f 0a> // that's the data value
too
tree
[ 'end', 'too', 'done' ]
for item: 1
starting 
..boo
<Buffer 20 79 6f 6f 6f 0a>
too
tree
[ 'end', 'too', 'done' ]
for item: 2
starting 
..boo
<Buffer 20 79 6f 6f 6f 0a>
too
tree
[ 'end', 'too', 'done' ]
```

Is this good for you?

Metux